# WM_MOUSEWHEEL during DoDragDrop?

Tags: c++, winapi, drag-and-drop, ole

We have a legacy C++ Win32 application that uses OLE DoDragDrop to handle drag & drop. Is it possible to receive mouse wheel messages while drag and drop is going on?

My instance of `IDropTarget` implements the following callbacks:

```
virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE DragEnter(IDataObject *pDataObj, DWORD dwGrfKeyState, 
    POINTL pt, DWORD *pdwEffect) override;
virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE DragOver(DWORD dwGrfKeyState, POINTL pt, 
    DWORD *pdwEffect) override;
virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE DragLeave() override;
virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Drop(IDataObject *pDataObj, DWORD dwGrfKeyState, POINTL pt,
    DWORD *pdwEffect) override;
```

There is no callback for mouse wheel information. WM_MOUSEWHEEL events are dispatched to my window proc while *not* dragging something. During drag & drop, I don't receive any WM_MOUSEWHEEL events.

Comment: While in the DoDragDrop, your application is not pumping the messages, the DoDragDrop is pumping messages.  As I recall, from MSDN, there are some warnings & cautions about pumping messages while within the context of a DoDragDrop.  (I suspect the internals has pointers to certain messages, and if you pump your own messages the pointers could become dangling and invalidate the internal state of the DoDragDrop.)

Comment: You receive no message during drag & drop.

Comment: You can do it using a `WH_MOUSE` hook, your hook will get called with `nCode == HC_ACTION` and `wParam == WM_MOUSEWHEEL` when the wheel is turned during the drag loop. You can then send your own wheel message to the window under the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it's possible with hooks, but it's not pretty.

I install two hooks just before `DoDragDrop`, and remove them again when `DoDragDrop` returns.

```
HHOOK hHook = ::SetWindowsHookEx(
    WH_MOUSE, // high-level mouse events
    ::MouseHookProc,
    nullptr,
    ::GetCurrentThreadId() // we're interested in our own events only
);

HHOOK hHook2 = ::SetWindowsHookEx(
    WH_MOUSE_LL, // low-level mouse events
    ::MouseLLHookProc,
    ::GetModuleHandle(nullptr), // WH_MOUSE_LL can only be watched globally
    0
);

HRESULT hResult = ::DoDragDrop(
    pData,
    pSrc,
    DROPEFFECT_COPY | DROPEFFECT_MOVE | DROPEFFECT_LINK,
    &dwEffect
);

if (hHook) ::UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
if (hHook2) ::UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook2);
```

The low-level hook has access to the mouse wheel delta, but it doesn't know about the HWND the mouse is over. The high-level hook has access to the HWND, but it doesn't know about the mouse wheel delta. It appears the low-level hook is called first, so I just store the delta in a global variable and use that from the high-level hook:

```
int g_nLastMouseWheelDelta = 0;

LRESULT CALLBACK MouseLLHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
   {
      if (wParam == WM_MOUSEWHEEL && lParam != 0)
      {
         auto pDetails = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT *) lParam;
         g_nLastMouseWheelDelta = GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(pDetails->mouseData);
      }
   }

   // Always pass the event on through the hook chain.    
   return ::CallNextHookEx(nullptr, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MouseHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
   {
      if (wParam == WM_MOUSEWHEEL && lParam != 0)
      {
         if (g_nLastMouseWheelDelta != 0)
         {
            auto pDetails = (MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT *) lParam;

            // Since we pass our threadId to SetWindowsHookEx, we can safely 
            // assume that the hwnd belongs to us.
            MyWin *pWin = /* determine MyWin structure */(pDetails->hwnd);

            if (pWin)
            {
               // Posting a Windows message during drag & drop may lead to 
               // problems, so we handle the mouse wheel directly!
               WPARAM newWP = MAKELONG(0, g_nLastMouseWheelDelta);
               LPARAM newLP = MAKELONG(pDetails->pt.x, pDetails->pt.y);
               pWin->handleEvent(WM_MOUSEWHEEL, newWP, newLP);
            }
         }
      }
   }

   // Always pass the event on through the hook chain.    
   return ::CallNextHookEx(nullptr, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```